# Please verify Jump searching algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, search

Please verify jump searching algorithm that I have written and let me know if any bugs are present.
I have tested it from my end, but still would like to get it verified for any missing corner scenarios.

```
class JumpSearch 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
      int[] input = new int[] { 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610 , 670 };
      int target = 13;
      int output=-1;
      int step = (int) Math.floor(Math.sqrt(input.length));
      int lastIndex = input.length-1;
      int index=step; //directly jump to end of first block.
      System.out.println("step : " + step);
      System.out.println("start index : " + index);
      System.out.println("lastIndex : " + lastIndex);

      boolean jumpBlocks = true , endOfInput=false;;
        while(jumpBlocks)
        {
          if(target <= input[index])
          {
            int previousIndex = (index-step);
            System.out.println("previous index : " + previousIndex);
            for(int a=index ; a >= previousIndex ; a--)
            {
              if(input[a] == target)
              {
                output=a;
                break;
              }
            }
            break;
          }
          else
          {
            if(endOfInput)
            {
              jumpBlocks = false;
            }
            else
            {
              index += step;  
              if(index >= lastIndex)
              {
                endOfInput=true;
                index = lastIndex;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      System.out.println("output : " + output);
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Review, please confirm if your code is referring to [Jump_search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump_search) and include yours tests.

Answer (score 4):

The sheer amount of breaks, and boolean controls, is an immediate red flag. It is a natural consequence of a decision to stuff everything into a single loop. Try to decompose the problem into a smaller chunks instead.

First, the `for` loop implements an important algorithm, on its own rights. Namely, **linear search**. Don't be shy, and factor it out into the function. At the very least, this would let you unit test it.

Next, notice that the `if` clause of `target <= input[index]` condition is executed at most once. Therefore, it doesn't belong to the `while` loop. The purpose of that loop is to find the block which potentially contains the target. This observation allows a simple decomposition, along the lines of

```
    int blockStart = findContainingBlock(input, target, step);
    if (blockStart == input.length) {
        return -1;
    }
    int blockEnd = min(blockStart + step, input.length);
    int index = linearSearch(blockStart, blockEnd, target);
    return index;
```

---

A side note about the linear search. The `for` loop is broken when the `target == input[a]`. You may as well break it when `target > input[a]`: there is no point to search any further. It means that

```
    for (int a=index ; a >= previousIndex && target <= input[a]; a--)
```

expresses the goals more clearly.

Besides clarity, notice that every block, except the very first one, has a natural sentinel: we are guaranteed that the last value of the previous block is less than the target. It means that the `for` loop doesn't need to test for `a >= previousIndex` at all:

```
    for (int a=index ; target <= input[a]; a--)
```

works, and has twice as few comparisons.

Dealing with the first block is also easy: before even looking for a suitable block, test whether the target could be there at all.

```
    if (target < input[0]) {
        return -1; // target is definitely not there.
    }
```

Now the first block is not special.